# Partial Differential equation with laplacian and gradient.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Suppose that $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open and bounded. Let $u\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C^0(\bar\Omega)$ is a solution for the equation $\triangle u+\sum_{k=1}^na_ku_{x_k}+c(x)u=0$ where $c(x)<0$ in $\Omega$. Prove that $u=0$ in $\partial\Omega$ implies $u=0$ in $\Omega$.

I ask for some advice to attack this problem, I do not know how to begin.

Thanks!

Comment: maximum principle. http://www.math.byu.edu/~klkuttle/547notesB.pdf from page 137.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you mean $u\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C^0(\bar\Omega)$. $u$ is a continuous function on $\bar\Omega$, which is compact, hence reaches its extrema.

Let $x_0$ be a maximum point. If $x_0\in\Omega$, then $Du(x_0)=0$ and $\Delta u(x_0)\leq 0$. By plugging this into your equation, we get
$$
\underbrace{\Delta u(x_0)}_{\leq 0} + \underbrace{c(x_0)}_{<0}u(x_0) = 0,
$$
and necessarily, $u(x_0)\leq0$. If $x_0\notin \Omega$, then $x_0\in \delta\Omega$ and $u(x_0)=0$.

Conversely, if $x_1$ is a minimum point, if it is inside $\Omega$, then
$$
\underbrace{\Delta u(x_1)}_{\geq 0} + \underbrace{c(x_1)}_{<0}u(x_1) = 0,
$$
meaning that $u(x_1)\geq0$. Like before, if $x_1\in\delta\Omega$, then $u(x_1)=0$.

Finally, for all $x\in\bar\Omega$,
$$
0\leq u(x_1) \leq u(x) \leq u(x_0) \leq 0
$$
and $u\equiv0$.

Comment: Very ilustrative, thanks! :)